# $ \lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}x\, e^{-x^2}\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^2}dt $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

Hello every one Please I need your help for the 3rd question, I tried but i fail every time.

for every real $ x $, we put $ f(x)=e^{-x^2}\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^2}dt $.

1. Show that $ f $ is odd of class $ C^{\infty} $ on $ \mathbb{R} $.
2. Show that $ f $ is a solution of the functional equation $ y'+2xy=1$.
3. Prove that $ \lim\limits_{x \to +\infty}2xf(x)=1 $.

thanks.

Comment: L'Hôpital with $e^{x^2}$ in the denominator should do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

I read the title and missed the hints. Here is a different way of computing the limit.

First, note that
$$
\begin{align}
xe^{-x^2}\int_0^xe^{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t
&\ge e^{-x^2}\int_0^xte^{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\frac12\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Next, note that
$$
\begin{align}
xe^{-x^2}\int_0^{x-1}e^{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t
&\le xe^{-x^2}\int_0^{x-1}e^{(x-1)t}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&\le\frac{ex}{x-1}e^{-2x}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
xe^{-x^2}\int_0^xe^{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t
&=xe^{-x^2}\int_{x-1}^xe^{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t
+xe^{-x^2}\int_0^{x-1}e^{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&\le xe^{-x^2}\int_{x-1}^x\frac{t}{x-1}e^{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t
+\frac{ex}{x-1}e^{-2x}\\
&=\frac12\frac{x}{x-1}\left(1-e^{-2x+1}\right)
+\frac{ex}{x-1}e^{-2x}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Taking the limit of $(3)$ yields
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}xe^{-x^2}\int_0^xe^{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\le\frac12\tag{4}
$$
Therefore, $(1)$ and $(4)$ imply
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}xe^{-x^2}\int_0^xe^{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac12\tag{6}
$$